# How do I write a minimal working example (MWE) in Coq to demonstrate some problem?

Tags: coq

To get help with some incomplete proof script or definition in Coq, or demonstrate some failing (e.g., Ltac) tactic or command, I am often asked to write a minimal working example (MWE) of Coq vernacular code. That is, I am asked to write, in as few and self-contained Coq sentences as possible, code that when executed by Coq leads to the error message I am seeing, such as a type inference failure.

How should I produce my MWE when the actual sentence that fails is in the middle of many lines of other Coq code? Specifically, is there any methodology or tools I can use to extract (and possibly generalize) the code leading up to the failure?

Comment: Here is some corresponding advice for Lean: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mwe.html

Comment: …and for StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://people.csail.mit.edu/jgross/personal-website/papers/2015-coq-bug-minimizer.pdf. “The Coq Bug Minimizer is an external script that will take any error- generating Coq file in the middle of a development, and after confirming that it has picked up the right error message, will automatically produce a small, stand-alone file which is guaranteed to generate the same error message.”

Comment: The Coq bug minimizer lives here nowadays: https://github.com/JasonGross/coq-tools